# Obtener info al seleccionar un punto en grafico de dispercion matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estimados estoy graficando un dataframe con matplotlib, la pregunta es si que al graficar los datos existira alguna manera de hacer click en el punto del dato y que me arroje mas datos sobre el punto seleccionado.

Les dejo el codigo.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
    'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
    'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
    'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
    'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})


df.plot(kind='scatter',x='num_children',y='num_pets',color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: Grafico scatter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción que quizás podrías usar es mostrar una ventana con la información que desees dar en el momento en que una persona de click sobre uno de los puntos, para esto necesitas una función  que te permita detectar cuando se haga click sobre uno de estos puntos.

Siguiendo la documentación de `matplotlib` nos encontramos con [esto](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html#object-picking), que nos da una idea de como proceder, un ejemplo bastante básico de tú planteamiento podría ser el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import easygui

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
    'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
    'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
    'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
    'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
    'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click on points')

line, = ax.plot(df['num_children'], df['num_pets'],'o', picker=5)

def onpick(event):
    if event.artist!=line: return True

    N = len(event.ind)
    if not N: return True

    for subplotnum, dataind in enumerate(event.ind):
        easygui.msgbox("Información que desees mostrar", title="Información")
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Sí te fijas en el `for` que se encuentra en la función `onpick`, ahí tú podrás colocar todo lo que desees mostrar.

Aquí estoy usando el módulo `easygui` para crear la nueva ventana que va a mostrar la información que desees, lo puedes instalar fácilmente con el comando `pip install easygui`

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, sera posible que dentro de ese msgbox se pueda visualizar un grafico?

Comment: Claro que sí, pero en lugar de desplegar una nueva ventana, puedes desplegar un nuevo plot, esto es, dentro de la función ```onpick```, antes del ```for``` creas un nuevo objeto pyplot, ```figi = plt.figure()``` y dentro del ```for``` ya puedes desplegar el plot: ```ax = figi.add_subplot(N,1,subplotnum+1)```  ```ax.plot("Nuevo plot")```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, otra consulta y si quiero que por cada punto aparesca un grafico diferente esto tambien es posible?

Comment: Claro que sí, dentro del ```for``` vas colocando las condiciones para los diferentes puntos